# spectrum of $-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ with respect to $C[0,2\pi]$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}$ denote the Banach space of all continuous functions $f: [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(0) = f(2\pi) =0$. Let $A$ denote the operator
$$Af = -f'', \qquad \text{Dom}(A) = \{ f \in \mathcal{B} : f \in C^2[0,2\pi] \}.$$

> I would like to find the spectrum of $A$.

Note that if $\sqrt{\lambda} \in \left\{\frac{n}{2} | n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$, then 
$$f(x) =  e^{i \sqrt{\lambda}x}- e^{-i \sqrt{\lambda}x} = i2\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x) \in \text{Dom}(A)$$ is an eigenfunction of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Therefore the spectrum of $A$ contains $\left\{\frac{n^2}{4} | n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}.$

Showing that this is all the spectrum where I am stuck. If $\lambda \notin \left\{\frac{n^2}{4} | n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$, I need to conjecture a formula for the resolvent $u =(A - \lambda)^{-1}f$, $f \in \mathcal{B}$, and then show it is a bounded map, and that $u$ is smooth and obeys the boundary condition. My best guess is that the resolvent is described using Fourier series
$$(A - \lambda)^{-1} f = \sum_{k = -\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ikx}}{k^2 - \lambda}\hat{f}(k), \qquad \hat{f}(k) = \int^{2\pi}_0 e^{-ikt}f(t) dt,$$
or some variant thereof.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can just solve the differential equation $-f'' = \lambda f$ and show all $C^{\infty}$ solutions with your boundary conditions are of the form you described. Wouldn't that be enough to show there's nothing else to the spectrum?

Comment: @Zarrax Thank you for your comment. I believe that would show injectivity of $(A - \lambda) : \text{Dom}(A) \to \mathcal{B}$ for $\lambda \neq n^2/4$. But then I would still need to show surjectivity and that the inverse is bounded.

Comment: You can solve $Af - \lambda f = g$ using methods for inhomogeneous ODE, incorporating the boundary conditions. There are explicit formulas for $f$ in terms of $g$ which you can get via variation of parameters for example. It might be possible to use these formulas directly to show the inverse operator is bounded. They should at least show surjectivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use variation of parameters to find a solution of the form
$$
        (A-\lambda I)^{-1}f=  \frac{1}{w(\lambda)}\left[\psi_{\lambda}(x)\int_0^xf(t)\varphi_{\lambda}(t)dt
   +\varphi_{\lambda}(x)\int_x^{2\pi}f(t)\psi_{\lambda}(t)dt\right],
$$
where $w(\lambda)$ is the Wronskian $w(\lambda)=\psi_{\lambda}(x)\varphi_{\lambda}'(x)-\psi_{\lambda}'(x)\varphi_{\lambda}(x)$, which does not depend on $x$, and $\psi_{\lambda},\varphi_{\lambda}$ are the unique solutions of $f''+\lambda f=0$ that satisfy the endpoint conditions
$$
       \varphi_{\lambda}(0)=0,\;\; \varphi_{\lambda}'(0)=1,\\
       \psi_{\lambda}(2\pi)=0,\;\; \psi_{\lambda}'(2\pi)=1.
$$
You find that there are simple zeroes of the Wronskian at the points of the spectrum; everywhere else the above expression defines a bounded inverse of $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$. The solutions $\varphi_{\lambda}$ and $\psi_{\lambda}$ are
$$
          \varphi_{\lambda}(x)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}},\;\; \psi_{\lambda}(x)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}(x-2\pi))}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.
$$
The Wronskian of these solutions is
\begin{align}
       w(\lambda)&=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}(x-2\pi))}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)\\ &-\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}(x-2\pi))\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \\
   &= \frac{\sin(2\pi\sqrt{\lambda})}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.
\end{align}
The Wronskian has simple zeros at $\sqrt{\lambda}=\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\cdots$, and a removable singularity at $\lambda=0$. As you would then expect, the spectrum is
$$
           \sigma(A)=\{ \pi^2, 4\pi^2, 9\pi^2,\cdots, n^2\pi^2,\cdots \},
$$
and the general element of the spectrum, $n^2\pi^2$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ is an eigenvalue with corresponding eigenfunction $\sin(n\pi x)$.

NOTE: If you find a discrepancy in the algebraic sign of this resolvent expression, or a missing constant somewhere, I'll let you fix that on your own. It's a good exercise for you to work through this example on your own using the classical techniques of ODEs.